# Sorting disk I/O errors in Python

Tags: python, exception

How do I sort out (distinguish) an error derived from a "disk full condition" from "trying to write to a read-only file system"?
I don't want to fill my HD to find out :)
What I want is to know who to catch each exception, so my code can say something to the user when he is trying to write to a ReadOnly FS and another message if the user is trying to write a file in a disk that is full.

Comment: @Sinan, "sort" as in "sort out", "fix", "repair". I always thought it was a peculiarly British term but @BlogueroConnor appears to come from Tatooine :-)

Comment: The wording seems a little unclear. Do you mean, you want to know how to distinguish between a "disk-full" error and a "file system is read-only" error?

Comment: Sorry, I from Argentina (I whish I were from Tatooine). Yes, I mean sort out, as  Craig McQueen put it: "to know how to distinguish between a "disk-full" error and a "file system is read-only" error?"
I need to give a msg to the user when he is trying to write to a read only file system and to give another message if he is trying to write data to a full disk.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you catch `IOError`, e.g. with an `except IOError, e:` clause in Python 2.*, you can examine `e.errno` to find out exactly what kind of I/O error it was (unfortunately in a way that's not necessarily fully portable among different operating systems).

See the [errno](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html) module in Python standard library; opening a file for writing on a R/O filesystem (on a sensible OS) should produce `errno.EPERM`, `errno.EACCES` or better yet `errno.EROFS` ("read-only filesystem"); if the filesystem is R/W but there's no space left you should get `errno.ENOSPC` ("no space left on device"). But you will need to experiment on the OSes you care about (with a small USB key filling it up should be easy;-).

There's no way to use different `except` clauses depending on errno -- such clauses must be distinguished by the *class* of exceptions they catch, not by attributes of the exception instance -- so you'll need an if/else or other kind of dispatching within a single `except IOError, e:` clause.

Answer (score 2):

On a read-only filesystem, the files themselves will be marked as read-only.  Any attempt to `open` a read-only file for writing (`O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR`) will fail.  On UNIX-like systems, the errno `EACCES` will be set.

```
>>> file('/etc/resolv.conf', 'a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/resolv.conf'
```

In contrast, attempts to `write` to a full file may result in `ENOSPC`.  **May** is critical; the error may be delayed until `fsync` or `close`.

```
>>> file(/dev/full, 'a').write('\n')
close failed in file object destructor:
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```